# Rails 4 devise4.2:How to use the admin account to change the user mailbox, but do not send validation mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

when I change user's email, devise auto send a confirmation_instructions email to target email.How do I cancel this operation?

```
user = User.last
user.email = "foo@example.com"
user.save
#the result is 
user.email  => "bar@example.com"
user.unconfirmed_email => "foo@example.com"
```

Comment: before you save you can give an command user.skip_confirmation!

Comment: Thank you.But not work to me.it's also send a mail.

Comment: how about user.skip_reconfirmation! , this with "re"

Comment: It works. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably can help other user

```
user = User.last
user.skip_reconfirmation!
user.email = "foo@example.com"
user.save
```